# How to scrape complex table in python?

Tags: python, sorting, html-table, beautifulsoup, lxml

So I am trying to scrape the betting odds off of a page, after trying many sites and finding that Beautiful Soup would not find ALL the required classes, I landed on this one. Problem is, its formatted really badly. Anyways, here is my code.

```
import requests
import lxml.html as lh

tennis_url = requests.get("http://odds.aussportsbetting.com/betting?competitionid=1", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36'})
page = lh.fromstring(tennis_url.content)
tr_elements = page.xpath('//tr')
print([len(T) for T in tr_elements[0:-1]])
```

Here is the site: http://odds.aussportsbetting.com/betting?competitionid=1

This shows me that each row has heaps of varying columns and that they've used a table to structure the whole website almost??

I really need some help and want to sort through all these rows and columns to just get the rows that I want. More specifically the odds :0

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: you may want to check this out. Use pandas read html https://beenje.github.io/blog/posts/parsing-html-tables-in-python-with-pandas/

Comment: I'd try using pandas if you need to read a table. `pd.read_html(url)`

Comment: I think you are doing it right, you need to modify the xpath so it is more precise. I can't  say exactly what it should be because I don't know what data exactly you want to scrape but try maybe with this:
"//form/table[2]/tbody/tr"